# right click not working in outliner - blender 2.8 on a mac

Tags: outliner

When I want to delete material in outliner, the right click is not working. I can't delete material. Also, the right click option is not working in all outliner panel (Cameras, Collections,Images etc.)
Hope somebody can help :)

Comment: Are you using the official release version of Blender 2.80?

Comment: Yes - I have downloaded from Blender site